# Can't perform git rebase

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase

I am an absolute beginner in Git and GitHub. I pushed my changes from my branch `issue-no-444` to one of the Open Source Repository but there were some conflicts. I resolved the conflicts through GitHub but I did a mistake.
Now I am trying to rebase it in order to correct it and then force push it.
Can anyone check if my steps are correct?

1. `git rebase master`
2. make the desired changes.
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit --amend`
5. `git push -f origin <my_branch_name>`

I would be really great if someone could help me out in this.
Thank You.

Comment: I  would suggest not to rebase master, and if that open source project is being maintained by properly, then master must be a protected branch and you can not force push to it. Rather create a new branch from the branch you want to rebase, make your changes  and merge it to the original branch.

Comment: @CodeTalker: the five steps listed above don't rebase master (onto something else) but rather rebase some commits from the current branch (onto master).

Answer (score 1):

Your five listed steps are not *wrong*, exactly ... but they might not be *right*, exactly, either.  There is a lot to all of this, but as a Git and GitHub beginner, you might have less to *un*-learn from bad tutorials than most people do.

This answer got too big, so I'm going to split it into two parts.  This is just background; see my other answer for what I suggest doing.

#### Anatomy of a commit

When you look at `git log` output to view commits you've made, or use GitHub's web browser to look at a commit, you will see that each commit has a *hash ID:* a big ugly string of letters and digits, which is really a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of a large, random-looking number.  The hash ID of any one commit—say, some new commit you just made—is unique to *that particular commit*.  No other commit anywhere, in *any* Git repository, can use *that* hash ID, once your commit has it.<sup>1</sup>  This is *why* the number is so big and ugly: a shorter, easier-to-remember number wouldn't be unique.

Git uses the big ugly hash ID as a key in a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  The value stored under the key is the commit itself, which consists of several parts that use yet more hash IDs internally.  Rather than worrying about these particular details—you don't need to know them to use Git—we'll just consider the commit and its auxiliary pieces as a whole.  That whole contains two things of interest to us:

- It has some *metadata*, i.e., information about the commit itself, that we'll describe in a moment.  For now just note that the metadata includes your name and email address, and some date-and-time-stamps, for instance.
- It has a *full snapshot of every file*.  This snapshot is in a compressed, read-only, and Git-only form, in which the file contents are *de-duplicated* in advance.  This means that if we check out some existing commit with a thousand files in it, change *one* file, and make a new commit from the result, Git doesn't really store 1000 files again.  Instead, it *re-uses* 999 files, and stores just the one updated file as "all new".  Or, if we change that one file to match the way it was in some earlier commit, it re-uses 999 files from the last commit *and* re-uses the one file from the earlier commit too.

It's always safe for Git to do this, because *everything about a commit, including both its metadata and its snapshot, is read-only.*  No part of any Git commit can ever change.  Once made, that hash ID means *that* commit, which has *that* saved content—forever, or at least, as long as the commit itself continues to exist.<sup>2</sup>  Meanwhile, this means that whenever we join up two separate Git repositories—as we will with `git push`, for instance—the two Gits can easily tell which commits they *share*, and which ones are *unique to one particular repository*.  That's because two commits are *the same commit* if and only if they have the same hash ID.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, two Git repositories can re-use a hash ID as long as they never "meet".  However, rather than attempting to do something this fancy, Git just tries to make sure that no two Git repositories ever re-use a hash ID at all.  Over time, for various reasons, this is getting harder, and Git will switch to even bigger hash IDs someday.  The way you use Git won't really change, but you may notice that cut-and-paste of a hash ID suddenly takes 64 characters instead of 40.  The details of this future changeover are not nailed down yet, though.

<sup>2</sup>Commits are therefore read-only (entirely) and permanent (mostly).  The *mostly* part of the permanence is complicated, as we'll see later.  The way this particular magic works has to do with the cryptographic hashing functions that Git applies to the stored data: the hash ID is the key, and Git just makes sure that no two commits have the same data-and-metadata, in part by sticking those time stamps into them.

(It is possible, but tricky, to make two commits using all the same files and history, *and* at the same time, and hence wind up with just one commit.  But when we write a program that does that—it's impossible for humans, who can't type that fast—why do we care whether it makes one commit or two, given that the two commits were 100% identical?  I have done this experimentally as a test, and there is a bit of side weirdness, but it actually all works fine.)

---

#### The metadata strings commits together

Now that you know what a commit is—a uniquely-numbered (hash-ID-ed) thing that stores metadata and a snapshot—you're ready to understand Git.  Well, almost.   Let's add one more thing here: each commit stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of some *earlier* commits.  Most commits store exactly one hash ID, of their *immediate predecessor*.

Take that in for a moment, then imagine we have a tiny repository, with (say) just eight commits in it.  The *last* commit has some big ugly random-looking hash ID.  To avoid having to deal with it, let's just call this commit `H`, with `H` standing for Hash and/or being the eighth letter of the alphabet.  Let's draw this commit, just floating out in space:

```
              H
```

Commit `H` stores a snapshot and metadata.  The metadata says that you (or I or someone, anyway) made commit `H` at some time in the past or future<sup>3</sup> ... but it also contains the raw hash ID, big and ugly, of one *earlier* commit.  Let's call that commit `G` and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

I've added an arrow coming out of `H`, pointing backwards to earlier commit `G`.  But `G` is a commit, so like every commit, it has a snapshot and metadata, and its metadata point to another, still-earlier commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This works all the way back to the very first commit, which we'll call `A`.  Since `A` *is* the first commit, it literally *can't* point backwards to anything earlier, so it just doesn't.  This special case—a commit that doesn't point backwards—has a name: it's a *root* commit.  You don't really need to remember the name though.  You just need to remember that commits point *backwards*, except when they can't because there's nothing earlier.

This backwards-looking chain means that as long as we can have Git find the *last* commit somehow, Git itself can work backwards from there.  So we only need to remember the big ugly hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain:

```
A--...--G--H   <-- (we need to save H's hash ID somewhere)
```

Given `H`'s hash ID, Git can find the contents of `H` in its big database of all its Gitty "objects", and from those contents, Git can find `G`'s hash ID.

Git can also *compare* the snapshots in `G` and `H` and tell you *which files changed*.  In fact, Git has a big fancy *diff engine*, so that it can show you the individual changed lines within those changed files.  All of this comes from the snapshot-and-metadata, with Git using the backwards-looking connection from `H` to `G`.

Having done this for commit `H`, Git can now step back to commit `G`.  This gives Git access to earlier commit `F`, and Git can compare the two snapshots here as well.  This is how `git log -p` shows you what *changed*, while also showing you each commit, one at a time.  Git just keeps walking back, one hop at a time, from commit to parent-commit.  The result *is* the history in the Git repository.

This is the first key what-Git-is-about item: **The commits in the repository are the history.**  That's all there really is to it: history is nothing but commits.  Git *finds* the commits by, somehow, having the hash ID of the *latest* commit: commit `H` in our example here.  But: how?

---

<sup>3</sup>The time stamps in the commit default to coming from your computer's clock.  Is your clock right?  Maybe I've set mine to next year for some reason.  (Also, anyone can override either or both of the two time stamps in the commit.)

---

#### Branch names find commits

One way we could use Git would be to jot down, on paper or a whiteboard, the hash ID of the latest commit.  Then we'd have to look that up and carefully type it in.  That would be ... ridiculous.  We have a *computer*, after all.  Why not have the *computer* store the hash ID of the last commit?

That's just what a branch name is and does for us.  Besides its big database of all internal Git *objects* (commits and the auxiliary objects), Git has a second, usually-much-smaller, database of *names*.  These names store hash IDs.  In the case of *branch* names, these names are constrained to store only *commit* hash IDs.  You don't need to worry about the other names, at least not yet.<sup>4</sup>

The branch-and-other-names database is very ad hoc and not very well implemented.  In particular, these names are sometimes—but not always—used as directory and/or file names.  If your OS does case-folding, this means that branches named `Hello` and `hello` are sometimes the *same branch* and sometimes are *different branches*.  As a result, it's unwise to use mixed case in branch and tag names: try to stick to all-lowercase if at all possible, and be careful with Unicode names.  (GitHub stores these on Linux file systems, which are case-sensitive, so on GitHub these are always different branch names.  That usually just makes things even worse for you if you're on a case-insensitive system and having problems as a result.)

Getting back to the point, though, a branch name, such as `master` or `main`, just stores *one commit hash ID*.  Whatever hash ID is stored in this name, that commit is **by definition** the *last* commit in the branch.  What this means is that we should draw our eight commits like this:

```
A--B--...--G--H   <-- main
```

(assuming we're using the name `main`, as GitHub defaults to now; Git itself does not care but still *defaults* to `master`, so you may wish to rename your `master` to `main` when starting up with plain Git, rather than by cloning a GitHub repository).  We say that this name `main` *points to* commit `H`; commit `H` then points back to earlier commit `G`, and so on.

These branch names can point to *any* existing commit, but there's the one hitch: that commit really does have to *exist* in your repository.  So if we have this `main`, and create a new branch—say, `develop`—this *new* branch name must also point to some existing commit, such as `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

Our eight commits, which used to be on `main`, are now on `develop`.  And they're *still on `main`, too*.  All eight commits are now on *two* branches, because there are two names.  If we create a third branch name, also pointing to commit `H`, all eight commits are now on *three* branches, and so on.

The fact that commits in Git are often on *more than one branch*—and the root commit `A` is typically on *every* branch—is very weird if you're used to other version control systems.  But it works fine, as long as you remember that *on some branch* doesn't mean *only on one branch*.

You also need to know one more thing: **Branch names move.**  Before we get to this, though, we need to augment our drawings just a bit more.

---

<sup>4</sup>If it helps, note that *tag* names *can* hold commit hash IDs, but often instead hold *annotated tag object* hash IDs.  This is what makes an "annotated tag" in Git.  These annotated tag objects are stored in the big objects-database, just like commits; like commits, they have a prescribed format, where the data are machine-readable.  The annotated tag data includes the hash ID of some *target* object, usually a commit.  However, an annotated tag can point to any of the four internal kinds of objects directly, including another annotated tag.  We won't go into any detail here though.

---

#### `HEAD`: The current branch and the current commit

When we have more than one branch name, as above, we need a way to pick *which name we're using*.  We'll use a branch name like `master` or `develop` to pick a commit, and if all our branch names pick commit `H`, we'll pick commit `H` no matter which *name* we pick.  But we still need a way to say which name we've picked.

The way Git does that is to use the special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase like this,<sup>5</sup> to remember *which branch name we're using*.  Git will *attach* this special name to one particular branch name, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

This indicates that `git status` will tell us `on branch main`.  If we now run `git switch develop` or `git checkout develop`,<sup>6</sup> Git will "switch" from commit `H` to, well, commit `H`: not much of a switch at all.  But `HEAD` will now be *attached* to the name `develop` instead:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

---

<sup>5</sup>On case-insensitive systems like macOS and Windows, you can type `head` in lowercase and it—sometimes—works.  That's because of the way Git stores these names in the file system.  It's a bad habit, though, because it *doesn't* work on Linux, and moreover, it works *incorrectly* when you start using `git worktree add`.  Don't do it!  If you don't like typing `HEAD` in all uppercase, consider using `@`, which Git has as a synonym for `HEAD`.

<sup>6</sup>You can use either command here; both do the same thing.  The `switch` command is new, since Git 2.23, and was split off from the overly-powerful `git checkout` that "does too many different jobs".  Half of the things that `git checkout` can do are now done by the "always safe" `git switch`, and the other half—commands that can destroy unsaved work without you realizing it—are now in the new `git restore`.  When using `git checkout`, it's possible to use it in the destructive mode without realizing it.  It took years, but the Git folks finally realized that accidentally losing work is bad, and having a command that you *think* is safe, but isn't, is *very* bad.

---

#### Making a new commit advances the current branch

Let's assume here that you already know all about making new commits, and in particular, about Git's *index* [aka](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aka) *staging area*.  You check out branch `develop`, edit some files, run `git add` as required to update the index / staging-area, and then run `git commit`.  Git will now:

- collect from you all the metadata it needs for the new commit, including a log message;
- package up the contents of the index / staging-area to use as the new snapshot; and
- actually *make* that new snapshot/commit.

The new commit has a parent.  The parent is the *current commit*, which is commit `H`.  So the new commit—let's call it `I`, using the obvious next letter—will point back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

Having made this new commit, Git now needs to update *one branch name*.  The one branch name that Git updates is the *current branch:* the name to which `HEAD` is attached.  Since we just attached `HEAD` to `develop`, it's `develop` that now points to new commit `I`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If you add another new commit here, this continues in the obvious way:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

This is how branches grow as we work, one commit at a time.

#### Situations where rebase or merge makes sense

Suppose we now return to `main`, with `git switch main` for instance.  We can then create another new branch, or just make new commits right here:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main (HEAD)
```

This creates a situation in which `git merge` or `git rebase` might be useful.

Note: I moved `I-J` to the top, and `K-L` to the bottom, just to have things in alphabetical order, sort of.  There's no particular reason to draw the graph this way; we could equally use:

```
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

for instance.  The important parts are:

- the names, and where their arrows point (to which commits); and
- the connections from commit backwards to parent(s).

But drawing things the way I did makes it clearer what happens if we run `git merge`.  For instance, let's say that we decide that commits `I-J`, on `develop`, are good, and commits `K-L`, on `main`, are also good, and that we'd like to *combine the work* we did on each of these two branches.

We would then run `git checkout main` or `git switch main` if needed, and then `git merge develop`.  This all seems to work by *branch names*, but in fact, it really works by *commit hash IDs*.  Git takes our argument, `develop`, and uses that to locate commit `J`: the last commit on `develop`.  Git takes our current branch name, `main`, and uses that to locate commit `L`: the last commit on `main`.

**For `git merge`** (only), Git now executes the trickiest part: it finds the *best shared commit*, i.e., some commit that's on *both* branches, that's better than any other commit that's also on both branches.  That's why I drew the graph the way I did: it's easy to see that all the commits up through and including `H` are on *both* branches, and all the commits after that are only on one branch.

Git will therefore find commit `H` and call it the *best shared commit*, or, to use the technical term, the *merge base*.  Git can then compare the snapshot in commit `H` to the one in our commit `J` on `develop`, to see what we changed there, on `develop`.  Git can also compare the snapshot in `H` to the one in `L`, to see what we changed here, on `main`.

**The merge code now attempts to combine these two sets of changes**—the ones that Git discovered on its own by finding the merge base and using `git diff` twice—and attempts to apply the combined changes to the snapshot *from the merge base `H`*.  That is, we want to *keep the changes we made on `main`*, while *adding the changes we made on `develop`*.  Or, equivalently, we want to keep the `develop` changes while adding the `main` changes.

If Git is able to combine these changes on its own, Git will normally go on to make one new *merge commit*.  A merge commit is like any other commit except in one way: instead of *one* parent, it has *two*.<sup>7</sup>  That is, like any commit, a merge commit still has a snapshot and metadata.  It's just that instead of listing *one* previous commit, it lists both the usual previous commit—for `main`, that's commit `L`—and the other commit that you merged: here, commit `J`.  We can draw the result like this:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /    \₂
...--G--H      M   <-- main (HEAD)
         \    /¹
          K--L
```

In this case, I've also annotated that the link from `M` to `L` is parent #1, and that the link from `M` to `J` is parent #2.

We won't look any more closely at merges here.  Let's go, now, instead, to `git rebase`.

---

<sup>7</sup>Git supports more-than-two-parent merges, which Git calls *octopus merges*, but they don't really do anything particularly special and we can ignore them here.

---

#### Rebasing instead of merging

Let's suppose that we do have this:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main (HEAD)
```

but now, instead of *merging* `develop` into `main`, we decide that for some reason,<sup>10</sup> we really like single-parent-only setups.  Commits `I` and `J` would be fine except for two things:

- they don't have the changes from commits `K` and `L` in them, and
- they connect back to commit `H`, instead of to commit `L`.

To fix this, we want to "update" the two commits.

Now, the fact is—and we established this early on—it's literally impossible to change *any* commit.  We can't *update* commits `I` and `J`.  But `I` and `J` aren't their real names: their real names are some big, ugly, unpronounceable hash ID, that nobody can remember.  We can only *find* commits `I` and `J` by using our branch name, `develop`, to find `J`, and then having Git use that to find `I`.

So: suppose we had Git list out the two commits that are only on `develop`—i.e., `I` and `J`—and then make a *temporary* branch name, like `temp`, at commit `L`, and switch to that name:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main, temp (HEAD)
```

Now suppose further that we could tell Git: *Using commit `I`, find its parent `H`.  Figure out what we changed to go from `H` to `I`, and make those same changes at the current commit.  Use the result to make a new commit.*  We'll call this *new* commit `I'`: it has some big ugly random-looking hash ID, but it's Git's attempt to *copy* `I`, so let's call it `I'`.  Let's draw it in, making the assumption that Git is able to copy `I` on its own:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main
              \
               I'  <-- temp (HEAD)
```

Now we'll have Git do the same thing with commit `J`.  We'll call the new copy `J'`, to indicate that it's built by automatically copying `J`:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main
              \
               I'-J'  <-- temp (HEAD)
```

Now, as our last step, let's have Git *move the name `develop` here, and attach `HEAD` to it* and then drop the temporary branch entirely.  The result is this:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main
              \
               I'-J'  <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we run `git log` now, it will *look like* we somehow *moved* commits `I` and `J`.  We didn't—that's impossible, and if we look closely enough at the big ugly hash IDs, we will see that we got all-new ones—but because the way Git *finds* commits is to start with our branch name (`develop` now selects `J'`), we'll see commit `J'`, then commit `I'`, then commit `L`, then commits `K` and `H` and so on, in Git's usual backwards fashion.

Since we can't even *find* commits `I` and `J` any more, we can stop drawing them.  That means we don't need the kink from `H` to `K` either:

```
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
               \
                I'-J'  <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we don't keep the little prime marks (tick marks) after `I` and `J`, we might even think we moved the commits.

**This is what rebase is about: we have some existing commits, which are okay-ish but have some sort of defect, mostly having to do with *where* they are.  We have Git copy those commits to new-and-improved commits, then yank the *branch name* off the old commits and paste it on to the new ones.**

#### Introducing one Git repository to another

Let's go back to our definition of a Git repository again:

- It's database full of commits (and other internal objects) that have hash IDs
- plus a smaller database of names that let us / Git *find* the *last* commits.

The names plus the commits themselves are the central part of a repository.  When we *check out* a commit, we extract its snapshot to a place we can see it, work on it, build software out of it, and so on, but that's not very important  ... at least not to Git itself, which is all about the *commits*, not about getting actual work done.

We need one other piece of information here, namely, that each Git repository has *its own* names.  The two Git repositories can see the other's names (to some extent anyway) when we connect them, but they don't *share* the names.  They *share* the *commits*.

We pick one Git repository to be a sender, and one to be a receiver.  Since we are probably on a laptop or something, and have a server site like GitHub, we need to be able to pick our laptop to be either the sender *or* the receiver.<sup>8</sup>

To have our laptop *send to* GitHub, we run `git push`.  To have our laptop *receive from* GitHub, we run `git fetch`—not `git pull`!  We'll come back to `git pull` again later.  In a terrible—or maybe trivial and minor—mistake early on, the Git folks made `git pull` do *two* things: first, it runs `git fetch`, then it immediately runs a second Git command.  The *transfer* part, though, is just that first command, and that's what we want to look at here.

Regardless of whether we're sending (`git push`) or receiving (`git fetch`), though, we'll need a *URL*.  The URL for a GitHub repository is often `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` for instance.  Rather than forcing us to type in this URL every time, though, Git gives us something it calls a *remote*.  The standard first remote is named `origin`.  When you use `git clone` to copy a repository's commits, Git sets up this standard first remote, and saves the URL.  When you create the repository initially on your laptop, you'd use `git remote add origin url` to set up the name `origin` to remember the URL.

Either way, once we have this URL set up, we can just refer to the other Git repository as `origin`.  That's pretty convenient, because as it turns out, we're going to have to refer to that other Git repository quite often.

---

<sup>8</sup>It might occasionally be nice to do both, but Git's design says that we must do that in two steps: by receiving first, then sending, usually.

---

#### Getting commits: `git fetch`

To *get* commits *from* the other Git repository, we can run `git fetch origin`, or even just `git fetch`.  This uses the saved URL to call up the other Git handler and connect to the other repository.  They then list out their names (branch and others) and corresponding hash IDs.  Your Git then takes these name-and-hash-ID pairs and remembers them.  It then checks to see if you have the *last* commit of each of their branches.

For any commit that you're *missing*, your Git asks their Git to send it.  Their Git must then offer the *parent(s)* of that commit too.  Your Git checks your laptop repository and asks for those commits, or says "I have them already".  Since the hash ID of each commit uniquely represents *that* commit, your laptop and their Git quickly figure out which commits—and hence files—you already have, and which ones you need.  They then package up all the commits, and any needed files (skipping any files you already have), and send this over to your Git.  Your Git deposits the new commits and other auxiliary data into your repository: you now have all the commits they have, plus any you have that they don't.

Now the other bit of magic kicks in.  **Your Git takes each of their *branch* names and changes it.**  Your Git turns their `main` or `master` into your `origin/main` or `origin/master`.  Your Git turns their `develop` into your `origin/develop`.  Your Git now creates or updates each of your *remote-tracking names* based on each of their *branch* names.

These `origin/*` names, in your repository, remember—for you and your Git—what *their* **branch** names were, at the time you ran this `git fetch`.  This information can grow out of date over time, because someone could be sending new commits *to* the GitHub repository.  If so, you'll need to run `git fetch` again.

The key items here are this:

- `git fetch` gets all the *commits* you need from them;
- `git fetch` turns their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names.

So if your `main` and your `origin/main`—their `main`—both identify the *same* last commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
```

your repository and their repository have the same *last* commit on your branch `main` and their branch `main`.  If they've *added* some commits, your Git will now have these new commits in *your* repository too:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          P--Q   <-- origin/main
```

#### Sending commits: `git push`

To *send* commits *to* them, you might run:

```
git push origin develop
```

which tells your laptop Git: *Call up the other Git at `origin`, then give him any commits I have on my `develop` that he doesn't have at all*.

This first part is the same as `git fetch` with two obvious differences:

1. You're now *sending* commits.
2. You have to specify *which branch name* to use.

As before, your Git and their Git will have a conversation, and figure out a minimal set of stuff-to-send.  Your Git then sends the commits and any auxiliary pieces needed.  But now there's a *third* difference from `git fetch`.  *Their* Git is not going to set a *remote-tracking name*.  They don't *use* those: they only have their *branch* names.

So, when you use `git push origin develop`, the final step is:

- Ask (regular push) or command (`git push --force`) their Git to set *their* **branch** name to record the same last commit as in your repository.

Because Git—any Git, including theirs—*finds* commits using a branch name and then working backwards, your `git push` here *could* **remove** commits from their branch.  If the new commits you send do not just *add on* to their branch, they will automatically say *no* to a regular (non-forced) push.  Command-line Git gives you a rather obscure message saying that the push is rejected as a *non-fast-forward*.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68225863/1256452) for definitions and background.  One other note: *GitHub forks complicate things*.  You may already be thinking that this is terribly complicated (and it isn't exactly simple).  Adding a GitHub fork to the equation makes it *more* complicated.  If you're using a fork, say so.  If not, we'll completely ignore this here.

#### What you'll need to do

You suggested these five steps:

> 1. `git rebase master`
> 2. make the desired changes.
> 3. `git add .`
> 4. `git commit --amend`
> 5. `git push -f origin <my_branch_name>`

Step 1 won't do any good unless your own branch name `master` has moved.

You *could* get your own `master` to move using `git checkout master`, `git fetch origin` (to update `origin/master`), and `git rebase origin/master` or `git merge --ff-only origin/master`.  However, it's easier and simpler to avoid all the extra motion: just run `git fetch origin` and your `origin/master` is now in sync with the other Git's `master`.  You can now stay on your branch and run:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This may encounter merge conflicts (each commit-copy step *is* a kind of `git merge`).  If so, resolve the conflict, `git add` the correctly-resolved files, and use `git rebase --continue` to proceed to copy the next commit.

Step 2 is necessary and appropriate: you definitely want to make any required changes.  Step 3, `git add`, is how you update Git's index for the next commit.

Step 4, `git commit --amend`: this makes sense only in one special case.  What `git commit --amend` does is to make a new commit *almost* as usual, but with one difference.

Normally, we have some set of commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- xyzzy-branch (HEAD)
```

and we make a new commit `K` and Git inserts it after `J`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- xyzzy-branch (HEAD)
```

With `--amend`, instead of making the new commit have the *current* commit as its parent, `git commit` makes the new commit have the *current commit's parent(s)* as its parent(s).  (The plural part makes this work for merge commits.)  So you get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--K   <-- xyzzy-branch (HEAD)
           \
            J   [abandoned]
```

The old branch-tip commit, here `J`, is no longer *findable*.  Using `git log` shows the new commit `K`, preceded by commit `I`.  The commit *seems* to have changed, but in fact, it's been discarded, replaced with a new-and-improved version.

If you have several commits on your branch, it's somewhat unlikely that you want to just amend the *last* commit.  Instead, you might want to add a new commit, or several new commits, that fix up some aspect(s) of one earlier commit, one aspect at a time.  You can then use `git rebase -i` to *combine* these "fixup" commits with the commits they fix.

This technique is somewhat advanced, though.  If you do have only the one commit, `git commit --amend` may well be the way to go.

For step 5, you will indeed need `git push -f`, assuming that your branch name now exists in the other repository.  They are using it to find the old commit(s) that you are replacing with new-and-improved commits.  You need to tell them that they should in fact lose those old commits, in favor of these new and improved ones.

So, your steps are probably mostly right, except for #1.